# How can I transfer shape or database files to Terrasync without Pathfinder office?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, trimble, navigation, terrasync

I have point data in ArcGIS that I need to get onto my Trimble GeoXT (with TerraSync Standard).

I don't have Pathfinder Office.

Is there a way to transfer the data over so I navigate to the points?

Answer (score 2):

There is, sort of. You can use the [Trimble Data Transfer Utility](http://www.trimble.com/datatransfer/) (which is a free download) to transfer a shapefile to your GeoXT and use it as a "background" layer in Terrasync. That will allow you to see your points in the Terrasync map view along with your current location while you're out in the field. That will help you find your way to each point.

But in order to actually navigate to each point (meaning it is available as a Navigation Target and the GeoXT will show you distance and bearing to the point) you have to convert your points to a Trimble .WPT file and upload that to the GeoXT as Waypoints (as opposed to a Background file). You can do the uploading with the Data Transfer Utility but I'm pretty sure that you need Pathfinder Office to create the .WPT file.